# How to display a random html file on an onclick event using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a random html file out of four different html files, and am not quite sure how to do that. So far, I have tried the following code, but get an NaN error- the web browser cannot find the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    var allVariations = ["/exp1.html","/exp2.html","/exp3.html","/exp4.html"];
                    var randomizeVariations = allVariations[Math.floor(Math.random()*allVariations.length)];

                    document.getElementById('loading').onclick = function() {
                        if (document.getElementById('consent_checkbox').checked) {
                             window.location.href = + randomizeVariations;
                        } else {
                            alert('You need to check the checkbox to continue.');
                            return false;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
```

I realize I might be doing plenty wrong here, but I am new to programming, and am looking for a way to do this. So if anyone has any suggestions as to how to fix this, or have another way of doing it, I would appreciate it, because I have searched online for what seems like an eternity, and haven't yet found a solution yet.

Thanks,
Yash.

Answer (score 0):

You got redundant plus sign:

```js
window.location.href = + randomizeVariations;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost perfect.

The issue is, that in the line where you set the new URL, there is a `+`.

A unary `+` operator converts its operand into a number, so in this case, converts `randomizeVariations` into `NaN`.

When you assign it to `location.href` (obviously) you won't get the desired effect.

To solve it, remove the `+` operator:

```js
var allVariations = ["/exp1.html", "/exp2.html", "/exp3.html", "/exp4.html"];
var randomizeVariations = allVariations[Math.floor(Math.random() * allVariations.length)];

document.getElementById('loading').onclick = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('consent_checkbox').checked) {
    window.location.href = randomizeVariations;
  } else {
    alert('You need to check the checkbox to continue.');
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Ahh I get it now. Thanks a bunch! Also, removing the '/' character also helped, as I was pulling the files locally, and had not specified a route in the backend.